# listing products by Attributes prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

I am new in the prestashop 1.6 development, I want to create a module that allows to list the products according to their different attributes
example: we have jeans pants with two colors (black and blue) and two size (L, XL), the page displays four products (black L, black XL, blue L, blue XL), as shown in the picture
[listing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ6gp.jpg)

can you guide me to succeed this module

Answer (score 3):

There's a paid module that's perfect to achieve this: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/combinaisons-customization/31071-show-combinations-or-product-attributes-in-product-list.html

Alternately, you can also override the getProducts() method present in the Category class an called in the Category controller.

Here's a basic example compatible with PrestaShop 1.6.x versions:

1. Create an empty Category.php file in /override/classes/
2. Delete the file /cache/class_index.php
3. Add the getProducts() method in /override/classes/Category.php

```
class Category extends CategoryCore
{
    public function getProducts($id_lang, $p, $n, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, $get_total = false, $active = true, $random = false, $random_number_products = 1, $check_access = true, Context $context = null)
    {
        if (!$context) {
            $context = Context::getContext();
        }

        if ($check_access && !$this->checkAccess($context->customer->id)) {
            return false;
        }

        $front = in_array($context->controller->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront'));
        $id_supplier = (int)Tools::getValue('id_supplier');

        /** Return only the number of products */
        if ($get_total) {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(cp.`id_product`) AS total
                    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
                    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa ON pa.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
                    WHERE cp.`id_category` = '.(int)$this->id.
                ($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').
                ($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '').
                ($id_supplier ? 'AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '');

            return (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($sql);
        }

        if ($p < 1) {
            $p = 1;
        }

        /** Tools::strtolower is a fix for all modules which are now using lowercase values for 'orderBy' parameter */
        $order_by  = Validate::isOrderBy($order_by)   ? Tools::strtolower($order_by)  : 'position';
        $order_way = Validate::isOrderWay($order_way) ? Tools::strtoupper($order_way) : 'ASC';

        $order_by_prefix = false;
        if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'date_add' || $order_by == 'date_upd') {
            $order_by_prefix = 'p';
        } elseif ($order_by == 'name') {
            $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
        } elseif ($order_by == 'manufacturer' || $order_by == 'manufacturer_name') {
            $order_by_prefix = 'm';
            $order_by = 'name';
        } elseif ($order_by == 'position') {
            $order_by_prefix = 'cp';
        }

        if ($order_by == 'price') {
            $order_by = 'orderprice';
        }

        $nb_days_new_product = Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT');
        if (!Validate::isUnsignedInt($nb_days_new_product)) {
            $nb_days_new_product = 20;
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) AS quantity'.(Combination::isFeatureActive() ? ', IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute, 0) AS id_product_attribute,
                    product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity' : '').', pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`,
                    pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, image_shop.`id_image` id_image,
                    il.`legend` as legend, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, cl.`name` AS category_default,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB("'.date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00",
                    INTERVAL '.(int)$nb_days_new_product.' DAY)) > 0 AS new, product_shop.price AS orderprice, pa.id_product_attribute
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').
                (Combination::isFeatureActive() ? ' LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop
                ON (p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')':'').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 0).'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl
                    ON (product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
                    AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl
                    ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa ON pa.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_image` pai ON (pai.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_shop` image_shop ON (image_shop.`id_image` = pai.`id_image` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il
                    ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image`
                    AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m
                    ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                WHERE product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'
                    AND cp.`id_category` = '.(int)$this->id
                    .($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '')
                    .($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '')
                    .($id_supplier ? ' AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '');

        if ($random === true) {
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '.(int)$random_number_products;
        } else {
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.(!empty($order_by_prefix) ? $order_by_prefix.'.' : '').'`'.bqSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way).'
            LIMIT '.(((int)$p - 1) * (int)$n).','.(int)$n;
        }

        $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql, true, false);

        if (!$result) {
            return array();
        }

        if ($order_by == 'orderprice') {
            Tools::orderbyPrice($result, $order_way);
        }

        /* Extended name */
        foreach ($result as &$p)
        {
            $attributes = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
            SELECT al.name
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_lang al
            WHERE al.id_attribute IN (SELECT pac.id_attribute FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_combination pac WHERE pac.id_product_attribute = '.(int)$p['id_product_attribute'].')
            AND al.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang);

            $extended_name = $p['name'].' (';
            foreach ($attributes as $a)
                $extended_name .= $a['name'].', ';

            $p['name'] = rtrim($extended_name, ', ').')';
        }

        /** Modify SQL result */
        return Product::getProductsProperties($id_lang, $result);
    }
}
```

This will display all the combinations available for each product and also select the right cover picture as well as a detailed name (e.g. "My dress (Red, M)"). This example isn't perfect though, pagination and stock also have to be tweaked but you get the point.